# How can I resolve PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=0} on getBuyIntent

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

ServiceConnection works fine and can i make getPurchases correctly but i can't buy product. this code are in a fragment

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = iabService.getBuyIntent(3, getActivity().getPackageName(), sku, "inapp", null).getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
getActivity().startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 42, new Intent(), 0, 0, 0);
```

and i receive popup with "the item you requested is not available for purchase" and this is log. i make question because there isn't any with type=3 subtype=0.

```
D/Finsky: [12320] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: it.localhost.itracking: Account determined from installer data - [zgXmi3sMHad8nr8tOaCFW_uVDgo]

I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.IabV3Activity (has extras)} from uid 10024 on display 0

V/GLSActivity: AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity: AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity: AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }

I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.IabV3Activity: +350ms

I/WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
I/qtaguid: Failed write_ctrl(u 19) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 19 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(19) failed with errno -22
D/Finsky: [1] PurchaseFragment.onStateChange: Error: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=0}
D/Finsky: [1] PurchaseFragment.onStateChange: Purchase failed: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=0}
```

another info is that app born in eclipse and works, when i move project to android studio i receive this error.

Comment: In my case problem was in different vesions of app in GP and on device. I.e. in GP was 1.2 and on device was 1.3. I found solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin/issues/99#issuecomment-162157937)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED ALONE

i publish app in beta and i receive this error: i can upload and put as draft but i cant publish in beta

after some time i will able to publish in beta and also inapp works

i don't know why

Comment: i don't understand the reason but problem it's solved, i published my steps

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates you didn't put this version either production or beta or alpha in in-app billing console. Did you put your version in one of those yet?

Maybe you could look at this.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: this app are in production in store and works inapp. is just port from eclipse to android studio, signed with same keystore, deploy on device and start to buy same product.

Comment: so the production and eclipse build is ok, but android studio is not?

Comment: Well I think there still some different between eclipse and android studio build and IAP detects they are different build, you might need to put a version in the alpha or beta.

I think its really hard to make it works based on they don't even tell us {type=3 subtype=0} what's the subtype=0 means.

Comment: i will try to publish in BETA but i receive error. is strange, i can upload and put as draft but i cant publish as beta

Comment: In my specific case I had a higher app version code compared to the one from Google Play. Once I made a version downgrade so it matched between the device and Google Play (adb install -r -d MyApp.apk) I got it to work again. However, in the console there was a slightly different error: `PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=4}`. One more clarification: my app was in beta only at the moment of the issue.